# How handle change value of input select in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to build a form.

I have a `Class extends React.Component` that contains a `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      dataId: '',
      isactive: '',
    };
    this.handleCreateChange = this.handleCreateChange.bind(this);
}
```

This is the method to **execute** after the form submission
(I use dispatch to execute my action):

```
doCreateTarif = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let postData = {
      name: this.state.name,
      dataId: this.state.dataId,
      isactive: this.state.isactive,
    };
    console.log(postData);
    this.props.dispatch(createData(postData))
};
```

This method can handle all **input** changes:

```
handleCreateChange = e => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
};
```

Inside the `render()` function, before the `return`, I declare this:

```
const { data } = this.props;
```

**structure** `data` from `props` looks like this:

```
data = [
  {
    _id: "a1G23e25vaus6DVa7Sv",
    volume: 100,
  },
  {
    _id: "e1D23f25vaus6ASa7saA",
    volume: 100,
  },
]
```

Inside the `return`, I have a **form** that looks like this:
(I use `reactstrap` that's why my tags are like so: `<Form>`, `<CustomInput/>`, etc.) :

```
<Form onSubmit={this.doCreateTarif}>
<CustomInput
  onChange={this.handleCreateChange}
  type="switch"
  id="exampleIsActive"
  name="isactive"
  label="Turn on this if True"
/>
<Input
  onChange={this.handleCreateChange}
  type="text"
  name="name"
  id="exampleNama"
  placeholder="Nama"
/>
<Input onChange={this.handleCreateChange} type="select" name="dataId" id="exampleSelect">
  {
    data.map(item => {
      return (
        <option value={item._id}>{item.volume}</option>
      )
    })
  }
</Input>
<Button color="warning" className="px-5" type="submit">
  Create
</Button>
</Form>
```

This is result of `console.log(this.state)`:

```
name: "ad"
dataId: ""
isactive: true
```

The value of **state** `name` and `isactive` work fine.
but the value of `dataId` is just an empty string, `""`.
I just wanna set **_id** from `const { data } = this.props;` as `value` of `dataId` in **state**.

Comment: Depends how reactstrap is calling onChange for the select it has, when you log the name and value in the onChange, is it what you expect for the select? Also with a normal select in React you pass the current value into the select via `value`. I assume reactstrap has a similar mechanism.

Comment: To start with, you can add a log in handleCreateChange and see what values is being passed in case of select change.

Comment: I don't really understand the reactstap ```Select Input``` mechanism but it seems the mechanism is the same. @Dominic

Comment: yes I've try this one to show log the input values, but it still has an empty string @MyTwoCents

Comment: It will help to debug if you can add a fiddle or codepen of this.  https://codepen.io/  https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you've used the Input, with the upper case I, which seems to be a customized component. I think your **upper case Input component might not necessarily be paired up with the lower case option component.**

Or you might **try to put your onchange callback and name on all those option components**.

Or do you have a customized Select component for your drop-down list?

For controlled components, value attribute and onChange callback are both set on the input/select element. 
See how these components are used in react: [the select & option pair](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)